# SQL Server Concatenate JSON For Dynamic Queries

Tags: sql-server

I have a dynamic (I am passing parameters in a stored procedure) query in a stored procedure which results in a JSON string.  Similar to this:

```
@PropertyPK uniqueidentifier (Stored Procedure Parameter)
@search_term Varchar(50)
@limit int
@offset int
Declare @test Varchar(1000)
SELECT @test = '
SELECT Cast((
SELECT *
FROM Contacts
Where Address like ''%' + @search_term + '%''' + ' Order By ' 
+ @sort_by + ' ' + @sort_order + ' OFFSET ' 
+ Cast(@offset as varchar) + 
' ROWS
FETCH NEXT ' 
+ Cast(@limit as varchar) + 
' ROWS ONLY 
For JSON Path, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES )
as varchar(max))'
EXEC(@test)
```

I have been asked to return results from 2 queries in a JSON format but in one string.  Basically run one query into a variable and the second into another and concatenate them together and then deliver the results..  Can someone help me putting the result JSON  from the above query into a variable so I can do the same with my second query and concatenate them?  Can I do anything after the Exec(@test) to get the result into a variable?

Thank you..

Comment: Out of interest, why are you running the above SQL within an `EXEC`? Normally code is written like that if you have dynamic SQL, however, your entire query is one literal value; so it has no need to be within an `EXEC`.

Comment: Hi Larnu, my actual query is a bit big to put in here so I put an JSON example without any variables hoping you would understand.  Should have made that a bit clearer..

Comment: So is your real query actually dynamic? If so, it would help to post a more realistic representation; as the answer will be different (if it's not dynamic then there no need for the `EXEC` so setting the value is as trivial as using `SET @Variable = {expression}`).

Comment: Yes it is a dynamic one.. I will amend my query above.  I know if I didn't have a dynamic one it would be a simple as your comment :)

Comment: What is `@sort_by` and `@sort_order`? They aren't declared in your SQL, and they, along with `Where Address like ''%' + @search_term + '%'''` are terrifying open to SQL injection.

Comment: And why is `@PropertyPK` no longer in the `WHERE` clause? Please stop drip feeding the information. If you want help with this, you need to post fully representative SQL; if the volunteers here post based on the answer above and it's not valid because your SQL isn't representative why should they be taking to time to answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest query you've posted isn't dynamic either, so I'm unsure why you're using `EXEC`. As i mentioned in the comments, therefore, this is as simple as using `SET`:

```
DECLARE @PropertyPK uniqueidentifier; --SP parameter

DECLARE @JSON nvarchar(MAX);

SET @JSON = (SELECT *
             FROM Contacts
             WHERE PropertyPK = @PropertyPK
             FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES);
```

There's no need for `@PropertyPK` to be cast as a `varchar` to a dynamic SQL statement; just use proper parametrised SQL.

This is based on guesswork and the OP's latest (but clearly incomplete) question. If this isn't correct, this should get you on the right path, however, having information drip fed makes the question difficult to answer properly.

```
DECLARE @PropertyPK uniqueidentifier,
        @SearchTerm varchar(50),
        @Limit int,
        @Offset int,
        @SortBy sysname,  --objects have the data type sysname, aka nvarchar(128)
        @SortOrder nvarchar(4); --Guess datatype as it was missing in your sample

DECLARE @JSON nvarchar(MAX);

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);


SET @SQL = N'SET @JSON = (SELECT {Columns}' + NCHAR(10) + --Replace {Columns} with an actual list of the required columns (NOT *)
           N'             FROM dbo.Contacts' + NCHAR(10) +
           N'             WHERE Address LIKE @Search' + NCHAR(10) +
           N'               AND PropertyPK = @PropertyPK' + NCHAR(10) + --I ASSUME that WHERE is still needed
           N'             ORDER BY ' + QUOTENAME(@SortBy) + N' ' + CASE @SortOrder WHEN N'ASC' THEN N'ASC' WHEN N'DESC' THEN 'DESC' END + NCHAR(10) + --The CASE stops invalid sort orders
           N'             OFFSET @Offset FEETCH NEXT @Limit ROWS ONLY' + NCHAR(10) +
           N'             FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES);';

PRINT @SQL; --Your best friend
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL,
                   N'@JSON nvarchar(MAX) OUTPUT, @Search varchar(50), @PropertyPK uniqueidentifier, @Offset int, @Limit int',
                   @JSON = @JSON OUTPUT, 
                   @Search = @SearchTerm,
                   @PropertyPK = @PropertyPK,
                   @Offset = @Offset,
                   @Limit = @Limit;
```

One of the biggest things you need to note here is I have made the SQL ***SAFE***. Your SQL was wide open to SQL injection, which is a huge security flaw. If you don't know/understand SQL injection, I suggest reading about it now. SQL like you have above is a huge problem, and raw string concatenation is an awful idea waiting to be exploited.

Comment: Thank you Larnu..  I amended my sql again hopefully to show it being dynamic.  If I try to run this as you suggest sql server says it cannot run as it is dynamic..  Thanks for the casting tip.. though I am sure it errored without that as I am compiling a string but I'll check..

Comment: @DerekJee this is why I asked you to provide representative SQL. I'll update in little while/

Comment: @Derek, that latest version still doesn't need dynamic SQL.

Comment: @DerekJee I've updated my asnwer, but i'm confident your question still doesn't tell the true story.

Comment: Hi Larnu..  Thank you for your code.  I have got it to work for me.  I am sorry I made it hard for you, not my intention.  Initially the actual query was irrelevant and just wanted to get to the point where I could get the JSON in a variable.  I understand that you want to see the whole picture, which in turn did teach me a new way of writing the query to guard against injections.  Thank you for your help.. very much appreciated..